How to run transactions in parallel in Java Spring?
We have a initial transaction that does some prep-work. Now we would like to suspend the initial transaction and spawn N new transactions that do their own thing in parallel and wont interfere with each other.
Using REQUIRES_NEW will suspend the initial tx and then no more than 1 tx is spawned. NESTED suffers from issue that they all share DB connection so they will interfere with each other.
As an another layer of complexity, everything is project reactor pipeline with Flux and Mono.
How can I spawn 10 new Transactions, each with their own DB connections from 1 initial Transaction?
Edit
After some testing and checking I found some issues that I think are the root of the problem, but I can't figure out how to solve these.
Flux.fromIterable(ids) <-- Runs ton thread 1
.parallel(CONSUMER_TREE_PARALLELISM)
.runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
.concatMap(id -> {
      log.info("Thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getName()); <-- Logs Thread 2, 3, 4, ...
      return doSomething() <-- Everything here is still ran on thread 1

}).sequential()

doSomething is also a reactor pipeline with db read and write. I need for it to run on the separate thread and for each thread to have separate transaction.

To execute things in parallel, each thing needs its own thread. The typical way of doing this is through an ExecutorService.
When your thread that does the prepwork is done with the prep, it would submit the 10 other items of work to the ExecutorService, receiving a Future for each (which are placed in a collection).
Each item of work would manage its own transaction on its own DB connection scoped to its own thread.
Iterate over the collection to get() the result from each of the 10 items when they are done.
Then you can continue executing whatever comes next.

And can this executorThreead be done with project reactor? for example the usage of .parallel?

I've had a similar issue in the past (Spring Boot 1.x). Calling doSomething() didn't go through Spring's usual mechanism and didn't process any security or transactional annotations. The solution was to self-inject. For instance:
// annotations go here
public class MyBean {

    private final MyBean self;

    public MyBean(@Lazy MyBean self) {
        this.self = self;
    }
}

(The @Lazy is necessary, otherwise Spring Boot won't be able to provide any instance.)
Instead of calling doSomething() you now call self.doSomething(). It will use the same bean but instead go "through the outside", thereby allowing all annotations to be processed.
I think this still applies to Spring Boot 3, as https://www.baeldung.com/spring-invoke-cacheable-other-method-same-bean describes the same issue and the same solution (albeit with @Autowired instead of constructor injection).

works aslong as i dont need more than 1 transaction in parallel. I need 10 trasnaction with 10 connections. or somethin. Or atleast i need to be able to read in parallel from database. Otherwise i cant get any performance boost.

AFAIK each call should get its own transaction if doSomething() is annotated to start a new transaction for each call.

the issue with REQUIRES_NEW is that the calling transaction gets suspended. And this seems to be causing issues that no DB connection can be aquired or something like that.
